# I got an error in w3 total cache like this "Ignored Query Strings"

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I got an error in w3 total cache like this:

In order for database caching to work with WooCommerce you must add _wc_session_ to the "Ignored Query Strings" option in W3 Total Cache settings.

Guide me to how to solve this issue

Answer (score 4):

W3 Total Cache plugin -> Database Cache submenu -> Ignored query stems:

Please add **_wc_session_** word to input box.

If already written this word in the input box(_wc_session_) then delete it, click on **Save all Settings** button and write/add again and save it.

The error will be disappeared.

Comment: Save my day. TY